# PhoneGap and Xcode: Play and Stop a sound with the same button

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I've searched all the whole Internet to find a solution to my problem, but I didn't find it :(

So, I'm doing a SoundBoard app using Phonegap and Xcode and my problem is about stopping the sound from the same button I used to play the audio, but I can't do it, I think it's impossible for me!

This is a part of the Javascript with the Play and Stop functions and IsPlaying function, that I created trying to determine if the sound is playing or not using the variable SoundPlaying:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

SoundPlaying = false

...

function playAudio(url) {
            // Play the audio file at url
            var my_media = new Media(url,
                // success callback
                function() { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");},
                // error callback
                function(err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: "+err);});

        // Play audio
            my_media.play();
    }

        // Stop audio
        // 
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;

    }

    function IsPlaying(url) {

        if (SoundPlaying==false) { playAudio(url); SoundPlaying=true; alert('SoundPlaying is ' + SoundPlaying); }

        else { stopAudio(); SoundPlaying=false; alert('SoundPlaying is ' + SoundPlaying); }

        }

</script>
```

And then I tried to call the IsPlaying function from a button: if the variable SoundPlaying is false then play the sound and set SoundPlaying as true, ELSE stop the sound and set SoundPlaying as false

```
<button id='button' 
      style="background-image:url(imgs/image.png);"
              onClick = "IsPlaying('msk/sound.mp3');" >
</button>
```

It's like the ELSE part of the statement isn't checked, but the IF part yes.  Indeed i can see the alert window saying that SoundPlaying is true but not if I click on the button a second time....or a third...and so on.

Can you please help me??

Thank you very much!

Vittorio

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to deep into the code ...

What do you think about this solution?

```
// Audio player
//
var soundfile = null;

// Play audio
//
function playPauseAudio(src) {
    if (soundfile == null) {
        // Create Media object from src
        soundfile = new Media(src, onSuccessAudio, onErrorAudio);
        soundfile.play();
    } else {
        soundfile.stop();
        soundfile = null;
    }
}

// Callback 
function onSuccessAudio(){};
function onErrorAudio(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this one in my phonegap project, works great. I even with a pause button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide(elementID)
{
document.getElementById(elementID).style.display = 'none';
}

function show(elementID)
{
document.getElementById(elementID).style.display = '';
}
</script>

<img id="off" src="images/general/sound-off.png" width="40" height="32" onClick="show('on'); hide('off'); playAudio();" alt="on">
<img id="on" src="images/general/sound-on.png" width="40" height="32" onClick="show('pause'); hide('on'); pauseAudio();" style="display:none;" alt="off">
<img id="pause" src="images/general/sound-pause.png" width="40" height="32" onClick="show('on'); hide('pause'); playAudio();" style="display:none;" alt="on">
```

For the audio, i use the playaudio(), pauseaudio() and stopaudio() command in the onclick.
Hope this helps :-)